# UWP - How to get ListViewItem value with right click or right tapped wihout select none Listviewitem?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

hello I have a list of data (sqlite) loaded to a listview and everything works marravilla if I select a listviewItem and right click on it, but I want to get the current listviewitem (under the pointer) without selecting any listviewitem

what I want is similar to the application of "Microsoft to DO"

[image]

and I have the following sample code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="myList">
        <ListViewItem>Item 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 4</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 5</ListViewItem>

        <ListView.ContextFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="itemActual">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="see" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </ListView.ContextFlyout>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            //Content = myList.item ????

            PrimaryButtonText = "ok"
        };
        dialog.ShowAsync();

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My original answer wasn't correct so I decided to edit it.

First, create a field called `_selectedValue` with the type of your `ListView`'s ItemsSource items' type, I'll call it "MyClass":

```
private MyClass _selectedItem;
```

Then, register the RightTapped event of your `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" RightTapped="myList_RightTapped">
```

From there, get the DataContext from the `RightTappedRoutedEventArgs`:

```
private void myList_RightTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    _selectedItem = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyClass;
}
```

When your flyout's `Click` event is fired, use `_selectedValue`:

```
private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // Do stuff with _selectedValue
}
```

**Full example files:**

MainPage.cs:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    #region Fields
    private List<MyClass> _items;
    private MyClass _selectedItem;
    #endregion

    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _items = new List<MyClass>();
        _items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "O" });
        _items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "P" });
        myList.ItemsSource = _items;
    }

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Do stuff with _selectedValue
    }

    private void myList_RightTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        _selectedItem = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyClass;
    }

    public class MyClass {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() => Name;

    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWP.Sandbox.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWP.Sandbox"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="myList" RightTapped="myList_RightTapped">
            <ListView.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout x:Name="itemActual">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="see" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </ListView.ContextFlyout>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, excuse me what should I do in "`YourType`" makes me an error there ?, How would I get a message of "`Item 3`" for example in the content of dialog by right clicking on "`Item 3`"?

Comment: `YourType` is the type of the items in your `ListView`'s ItemsSource.

Comment: I have the following problem: [Screenshot problem](https://i.imgur.com/WqpdT0N.png)

Comment: @fausdev I have edited the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Amazing works great !!  Thank you very much, I will implement it in my project 